# How to connect 2 GSM Modems

Tags: serial-port, gsm, modem, duplex

I want to know how can i use 2 **GSM Modems** in **one computer** (using **Windows**)    ?
Those modem have a usb connector but the system plug them as Mobile Modem in COM Port.
The probleme is how to use 2 Modems togeteher in different ports.
The modem reference is ls100 and it made by Lonsai i connected 2 modems in my computuer but in devices manager i found the COM Port of the first one that i put. did some one have an idea how to detect 2 COM Ports ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using serial port then that is not possible ofcourse. However, if you are using USB to connect the modem, you can use different COM ports. Here are some steps you can try and debug the issue:

1. Please refresh your device manager settings and see if you can find another COM port.
2. Plug in the modems one by one to see if the COM Port appears for both. Note what number has been assigned to each modem.
3. Try using different USB ports on your PC.
4. Try using a different terminal to see the COM Ports or multiple terminals for each modem